# Limit of a sequence in fraction .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers

How to find the following limit ? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2+\cdots +\sqrt n}{\sqrt[6]{1}+\sqrt[6]{2}+\cdots +\sqrt[6]{n}}\frac {\sqrt[3]{1}+\sqrt[3]{2}+\cdots +\sqrt[3]{n}} {\sqrt[3]{1^2}+\sqrt[3]{2^2}+\cdots +\sqrt[3]{n^2} }$$ I tried it by [Stolz–Cesàro_theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) but didn’t get the answer. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh, this year NBHM question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The expression is equivalent to

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[6]{k}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{k^2}} =\frac{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac kn}\cdot \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\frac kn}}{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[6]{\frac kn}\cdot \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac kn\right)^2}}$$

which in the limit seems very manageble by Riemann sum.